# What will happen when you put variable as counter in a for statement?

Tags: vb.net, variables, for-loop, mono

Can anyone tell the value of counter at each iteration?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim x As Integer
        For x = 1 To 10 Step (x)
            x = x + 1
            MsgBox(x)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of this code. Why do you have a step of `x`, and why do you increment `x` manually when it is done by the loop? The `Step` and `To` parts are only evaluated once, so because `x` is zero before the loop (you never initialize it, hence it gets the default value of 0) the `Step` will always be 0.

Comment: Currently your code is equal to `For x = 2 To 11 : MsgBox(x) : Next`.

Comment: i just want to see how things works its not about the purpose of code its about how you will think .

Comment: Then it'll go from 2-11, not 2-10 like Arvind's answer states. The Mono compiler must have got a bug.

Comment: Can't you try this yourself so you can understand yourself. Like @VisualVincent has commented, I don't see why you would write code like this. It's very odd. This isn't puzzle.se :)

Comment: i just need to understant nothing more

Answer (score 3):

The iterations will be:

x=2

x=4

x=6

x=8

x=10

**But how?**

For the first time when you execute a loop the value will be x=1.

Later inside the loop the value of x becomes x=x+1 ie x=2.

Now this value is used as step so your code takes steps of size 2.

In VB once the size of a step is calculated it is not recalculated. For example here in the second iteration the value becomes x=4 that doesn't mean it will now take a step size 4. It will use previously calculated value ie 2.

[image: Proof]

Comment: That can't be right. `Step` is evaluated _**prior**_ to the first iteration **only**. Try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qPvM9i

Comment: @VisualVincent Sorry but that's not possible. Tell me how would you calculate step size before first iteration. Before first iteration the value of x is undetermined.

Comment: You are compiling in Mono. Did you find a different behavior than compiling with Microsoft .NET?

Comment: I think the Mono compiler has a bug. Ideone gives the same result as yours: http://ideone.com/MpUoAf

Comment: Integers are value types and therefore cannot be _undetermined_ (null). If you don't give an Integer variable a value then it will by default be 0. So yes, it is possible.

Comment: But step size of 0 is a infinite loop.

Comment: let to say the X between ( ) is a counter the value will be only 1 of iteration ?

Comment: This should solve the problem. [click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_fornext_loops.htm)

Comment: @Arvindsinc2 : Yes it is an infinite loop, and I bumped into that problem just a few minutes ago when I was trying it. But because the OP is using `x = x + 1` inside the loop that breaks the infinity.

Comment: `Step` is not doing the actual incrementing because prior to the loop, the step size is initialized to 0. `x = x + 1` is doing it in this case. So we increment by 1 and the values should be `2, 3, ... , 10, 11`

Comment: but at first time the step size will not be 0 because i say the x=1 to 10 step x so the step size wil be 1 not 0

Comment: What I said earlier can be confirmed by this snippet: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SSkMd6 -- As you see neither `x` nor `y` can be null. They're automatically set to their default value, which is 0.

Comment: I ran the code without x=x+1..it dint get into a infinite loop that clearly proves my point.According top you if step was 0 then on removing x=x+1 it should have been a infinite loop.

Comment: `...i say the x=1...` that doesn't mean you set x = 1. It's just the syntax of the `For ... Next` loop, and is not to be interpreted as an assignment of a value to x.

Comment: @MohammedKandeel : That's not how the .NET compiler _should_ work. The whole line should be evaluated before the variables are changed.

Comment: @Arvindsinc2 Microsoft .NET compiles it into an infinite loop. Please note that your tests in Mono aren't what most people will experience.

Comment: yes i'm with but when i said x= 1 to 10 that mean i make the value of x =1

Comment: It _**IS**_ an infinite loop if you use a real .NET compiler! Mono has got a bug. Try it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and see what happens (it will crash your browser though, so open a new instance).

Comment: So lets conclude that this works for mono and not .NET.. :-)

Comment: @MohammedKandeel : No it doesn't work that way. `x` shouldn't be changed until _**that whole line**_ has been evaluated.

Comment: @Arvindsinc2 : Yes, however it is still a bug since a real .NET compiler doesn't work that way :). Frankly I wouldn't have thought that such a basic thing could get missed.

Comment: If the question was tagged with `Mono`, it might be a different story

Comment: until now i dont understand that situation and if we take the step size as 1 if we replace the counter x between ( ) with value 1 the result will be changef so what that ?

Comment: @MohammedKandeel : Here's a little test (pardon the code indentation, dotnetfiddle apparently doesn't like mobile phones): https://dotnetfiddle.net/rIxX7o

Comment: what i understand the first time when x intiate with 0 not 1 but m=m+1 will beark it and the step size will still 0. so the result will be 2.3.....11.

Comment: @MohammedKandeel : Exactly. That is how it works in a normal .NET compiler. If you were to remove `x = x + 1` from the first loop in my link then your browser would freeze and/or crash due to that you've created an infinite loop.

Comment: one other comment  (didn't see it specified) - even 0 as step will exit, as the ending condition is still x < 10

Comment: @John : I'm not sure what you mean. As long as you increment `x` somewhere in the loop you should be safe from having an infinite loop, however if you _**only**_ have `Step 0` without incrementing `x` then you'll get stuck in an infinite loop. The loop will never end until `x` is at least 10.

Comment: @VV - yes, I was speaking specifically to the code as given.  coming in with step 0, initialized to 1 (in the for), with the increment specified in the body of the loop

Answer (score 1):

2-11 - Step(x) is evaluated when first called.  (I'm right, yes - do I get a cookie?)

Comment: i ask a bout counter not i mean x between  ( )

Comment: @MohammedKandeel : His answer was 2-11. The thing he said about `Step` was just how it works.